# How to set focus on DIV when the lightbox_me trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with only one focusable element button (close button), when the lightbox opens focus should be on div. when i press tab focus should goto 'close' button.

As per assertive technology(blind users) close button should be at the bottom of the DOM,that is one reason  DIV should be focus when lightbox triggers.

I have set

```
<div id="div-id"  role="dialog"  tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="operations-help">
```

and in jQuery set  :

```
$('#div-id').lightbox_me({
     destroyOnClose: true,
     onLoad: function() {
         $('#div-id').focus();
     }
 });
```

but focus is setting on close button only, is there any way i can set focus on DIV.

Thanks

Comment: you can try to set tabindex to the dic to make it focusable... jQuery("div.selector").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();

Comment: kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/fmatmzdb/  which demonstrates how to set focus to a div

Comment: kindly check this https://jsfiddle.net/fmatmzdb/1/ ... set div tabindex dynamically and at the same time set close button tabindex 1 higher than div

Comment: i have tried jQuery("div.selector").attr("tabindex",-1).focus() but it is not working, problem seems to be if a div contains any focus elements like button, a, input etc focus is going to those.

Answer (score 0):

A div can't take focus afaik. If the div has a button you could instead call

`$('#div-id button').focus();`

Or if I've misunderstood and the div is the button can changing the div to a button or submit input should allow focusing.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for quick response, but  div is having a close button, as per requirement it should NOT focus by default.

Comment: and in my research i came to know if we  add tabindex="-1" to DIV  it will get fous, but it is not happening.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that part- I don't think a div is normally focus-able - generally only elements with a tabindex can take focus - I wonder if setting a positive tabindex on the div and then calling .focus() on the element would work.  Testing in a regular browser didn't work unsure if it'd work with a screen reader but it's the best idea I've got at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.hash = '#div-id';
```

This will scroll to the element, essentially focusing it.

So finally,

```
$('#div-id').lightbox_me({
     destroyOnClose: true,
     onLoad: function() {
         window.location.hash = '#div-id';
     }
 });
```

I guess this should work.

Comment: Hi Shubhan, i have tried the above.. but no luck, the above code behaviour is same like   onLoad: function() {
         $('#div-id').focus();
     }

Comment: Ok lets search for another way then, I will update the post as soon as I go across something

Comment: issue is when i put a  debug point  on  window.location.hash = '#div-id', focus is on the dialog, once the  control comes out of onLoad focus immediatly going to close button.

Comment: and you want that to happen on press of tab key, am I right

Comment: ys when the lightbox appears focus should be on dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A div is not a focusable element.

A possible solution is to set a button/link with dimensions 1px by 1px somewhere on the corner of the div and set focus on it.

aria-labelledby could be then set on that button instead of the entire div :)

Do let me know if that works. If using a link, make sure you set href as #.

You could also, add a button and hide it. Not with display: none, but with z-index, so that it remains tabbable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to

```
$('#div-id').lightbox_me({
     destroyOnClose: true,
     onLoad: function() {
         $('#div-id').attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
         $('.close').attr('tabindex',2);
     }
 });
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('#div-id').lightbox_me({
    destroyOnClose: true,
    centered: true, 
    onLoad: function() { 
        $('#div-id').find('a:first').parent().focus()
        }
    });
```

here is the fully functional working demo  https://jsfiddle.net/jfy5n2nf/1/

**NOTE:** on pressing tab key focus shifts to close button and a red border appears

Comment: Hi  with the above code snippet  focus still going to close button

Comment: hmmm which plugin are you using for lightbox?

Comment: jquery.lightbox_me

Comment: well i was not able to recreate the UI but check this https://jsfiddle.net/jfy5n2nf/   here focus will go to close button on tabpress

Answer (score 0):

Hey you cannot focus div element but you can do a little work around and put after or inside of this div element that you can. Here is example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("test2");

div.addEventListener("focus", function(){alert("it's a test")});
```

```css
#test{
  width:200px; 
  height:200px; 
  background-color:#0CF; 
  z-index:1;
  }
#test2{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  width:100; 
  height:100%; 
  opacity:0; 
  cursor:default;
  }
```

```html
<div id="test"><textarea id="test2"></textarea>sdfsdf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix by setting property :focusPopover : false , this solved my problem.

$('#div-id').lightbox_me({
     destroyOnClose: true,
     focusPopover : false,
     onLoad: function() {
         $('#div-id').focus();
     }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Try it with HTML5 `contenteditable`

```js
$('#focusbtn').click(function(){
  $('#div-id').focus();
});

$('#div-id').on('focus', function(){
  alert('I am focusing in div!');
});

$('#div-id').keypress(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

});
```

```css
#div-id{
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-id"  role="dialog" contenteditable="true">
  I am the div. Please focus on me
</div>

<BR/>

<button id="focusbtn">Focus</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

position:fixed;

it will always be in the same position even when scrolling,
here is my code, it will be always on the center of the screen.

```
   .example
{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:800px;
    height:450px;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index:51;
    padding:20px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
    display:none;
  }
```